# Scala flatmap saving to cassandra via spark in loop

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, flatmap

I have loop with `Names{Real Test!, Real Test1!}` and inside it loop throw days (here as example iteration is 1 day only), in this loop some operations with data, and then I flatMap RDD(with 2 rows) to RDD with 5 rows. And on `collect().foreach(println)` it gave me this:

```
(Real Test!,2016-07-25,session_end,63)
(Real Test!,2016-07-25,app_open,63)
```

for first Name - and

```
(Real Test1!,2016-07-25,app_open,63)
(Real Test1!,2016-07-25,app_install,0)
(Real Test1!,2016-07-25,session_end,0)
```

for second. When i try to `saveToCassandra` all 5 rows in loop - in DB I only have last rows of flatMap.

```
id | name        | date      | count | event
1  | Real Test!  |2016-07-25 |  63  | session_end
2  | Real Test1! |2016-07-25 |  0   | session_end
```

Why it saves me only last row from flatMap, and how I can save ALL 5 rows?

Comment: what is the schema for cassandra table ?

Comment: If your primary key is (id,name,date) then this is the expected behaviour as the data with same primary key overrides the existing data.

Comment: xD yes, you right! Thank you!!

Comment: Don't even thinking in cassandra way ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the primary key is (id,name,date) then this is the expected behaviour as the data with same primary key overrides the existing data.

Comment: Your answer was poor quality. Please read about how to answer question on SO.